# Solving Terraform cycle for seemingly unrelated resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

When I try to apply a terraform configuration I get an error:

```
Error: Cycle: module.c.google_compute_instance_template.pull (destroy deposed 83fe0757),
module.o.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test,
module.h.google_compute_instance_group_manager.pull (destroy deposed ecd374e7),
module.o.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test (destroy),
module.o.docker_image.service,
module.o.docker_registry_image.service,
module.o.local.image (expand),
module.o.local.cloud_init_content (expand),
module.o.local.cloud_init (expand),
module.o.output.cloud_init (expand),
module.c.var.o (expand),
module.c.var.f (expand),
module.c.local.cloud_init_content (expand),
module.c.google_compute_instance_template.pull,
module.c.output.compute_instance_template (expand),
module.h.var.controller_template (expand),
module.h.google_compute_instance_group_manager.pull,
module.h.google_compute_autoscaler.pull,
module.h.google_compute_autoscaler.pull (destroy deposed 578e3a34),
module.d.google_compute_instance_template.pull (destroy deposed 79860500),
module.c.google_compute_autoscaler.pull,
module.d.local.cloud_init_content (expand),
module.d.google_compute_instance_template.pull,
module.d.output.compute_instance_template (expand),
module.c.var.donkey_instance_template (expand),
module.c.google_compute_instance_group_manager.pull,
module.c.google_compute_instance_group_manager.pull (destroy deposed adf15f71),
module.f.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test,
module.s.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test,
module.s.local.image (expand),
module.s.local.cloud_init_content (expand),
module.s.local.cloud_init (expand),
module.s.output.cloud_init (expand),
module.d.var.s (expand),
module.f.output.cloud_init (expand),
module.d.var.f (expand),
module.d.local.cloud_init_integration_test_content (expand),
module.d.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test,
module.d.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test (destroy deposed c4b1489e),
module.s.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test (destroy),
module.s.docker_image.service,
module.s.docker_registry_image.service,
module.c.google_compute_autoscaler.pull (destroy deposed 45f462e6),
module.f.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test (destroy),
module.f.docker_image.service,
module.f.docker_registry_image.service,
module.f.local.image (expand),
module.f.local.cloud_init_content (expand),
module.f.local.cloud_init (expand)
```

I cannot really make heads or tails out of it also - e.g.
`module.c.google_compute_instance_template.pull (destroy deposed 83fe0757)` has not dependency on `module.o.google_compute_instance_template.integration_test` or vice versa.
So I am wondering how to read the output and also how to go about fixing it.

Comment: What is your TF code?

Comment: Can you be more specific? With that many resources I think posting all will be a bit too much noise

Comment: The parts of code the create the "cycle" would be enough.

Comment: You can use terraform graph and a viewer to help debug this.

Comment: @MattSchuchard From my experience this is not true since this is not a cycle of plan but of apply/destroy, which is not shown with graph AFAIK

Comment: You can add a flag:  `-type=plan  Type of graph to output. Can be: plan, plan-destroy, apply, validate, input, refresh.`

Answer (score 0):

Basically we "solved" this by moving all

```
lifecycle {
  create_before_destroy = true
}
```

blocks out of the change.
It seems like terraform has a hard time figuring out graphs with `create_before_destroy` combined with other changes.